# Forbidden error when using kubectl to run "apply" on Openshift server

Tags: kubernetes, openshift

I have an OpenShift server I'm trying to work on. When I use:

`oc apply -f`

My request is successfully processed.

However, many tools I want to use for development expect `kubectl` to be used to connect to the cluster. In most circumstances, I can use `kubectl` with no problems.

However, in the case of `kubectl apply -f`, this fails with error:

`Error from server (Forbidden): unknown`

While running `oc apply -f` works as expected.

To try to bypass this, I created (on Windows) a symbolic link named "kubectl" to the `oc` executable. Unexpectedly, this caused the `oc` command to start behaving like the `kubectl` command, and again receiving the same error.

Calling the full path to the link, as well as simply renaming "oc.exe" to "kubectl.exe" produces the same error. I confirmed I was indeed calling the correct bianry by running `kubectl version`, and I received different results from the vanilla binary vs. the openshift wrapper.

Enabling verbose logging: `kubectl apply -f service.yaml --v 6` gives this output

```
I0625 13:09:43.873985   11744 loader.go:357] Config loaded from file C:\Users\username/.kube/config
I0625 13:09:44.175973   11744 round_trippers.go:436] GET https://myhost:443/swagger-2.0.0.pb-v1 403 Forbidden in 286 milliseconds
I0625 13:09:44.179974   11744 helpers.go:201] server response object: [{
  "metadata": {},
  "status": "Failure",
  "message": "unknown",
  "reason": "Forbidden",
  "details": {
    "causes": [
      {
        "reason": "UnexpectedServerResponse",
        "message": "unknown"
      }
    ]
  },
  "code": 403
}]
```

Running using `oc apply -f service.yaml --v 6` gives almost the same result, except that after the initial 403 error, I get the following output:

```
I0625 13:37:19.403259    7228 round_trippers.go:436] GET https://myhost:443/api 200 OK in 5 milliseconds
```

And the command continues on to work correctly.

Is there anyway I can bypass this odd behavior, and somehow use `kubectl` to successfully run `kubectl apply -f` against the OpenShift server?

**Edit:**

The `oc` binary wrapper uses kubectl 1.9.
The vanilla `kubectl` command uses 1.10.
The server is kubectl 1.6 and openshift 3.6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what client and server version do you have?

kubectl attempts to do client-side validation when it creates/applies objects. to do this, it first downloads the openapi schema. when making requests to an older server, that endpoint may not be recognized, and may result in a "forbidden" error

setting `--validate=false` when making the kubectl apply call will bypass that client-side validation (server-side validation is still performed)

Comment: I have edited and added the versions to my question. Turning off validation does indeed make the apply command function correctly.

Comment: kubectl and oc support one version of skew between client and server. exceeding that can lead to invalid client assumptions, like the availability of that discovery doc